# How to estimate the number of maximum users possible on a website?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, yii

I am building a PHP-MySQL website featuring an online contest and my client needs an estimate on the maximum possible number of users logged in at the same time that the website can withstand without slowing down. I have tried to minimize the number of HTTP request and even optimized it very much but I can not give a number of maximum users.
I have set the MaxKeepAliveRequests to 0 to disable the maximum cap.
The site is on a shared hosting server. Is there any method to estimate the maximum safe limit of number of users.
The site is built on Yii framework.

Comment: Use something like apachebench to simulate concurrent activity for different numbers of users, and look at the response times it gives... but it's up to you to decide what thresholds you want

Comment: If you are on shared hosting it is completely out of your hand. What if your neighbor runs a 10000 hits a second xxx site? Your done then.

Comment: @michael-borgwardt answers it correctly. However the estimate will be wrong as pointed out by jvdberg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance estimations are pretty much useless.

So don't estimate - measure. Use a load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or a service like [Blitz](http://blitz.io/) to *actually simulate lots of users* and see what happens.